What's a more formal equivalent of merdification?
fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merdification:

La merdification, ou emmerdification (du mot anglais enshittification) est la dégradation de qualité qui affecte progressivement les plate-formes numériques qui opèrent sur un marché biface, par exemple celles qui mobilisent à la fois des utilisateurs et des annonceurs.

What's a more formal equivalent of merdification?

Eventuellement "stratégie perverse d'assujetissement".

Most likely, no single-word term has been coined; it can be shown  that the definition of "merdification" itself, as it applies to the platforms, is not well established: "dégradation de la qualité des services sur internet", "lente dégradation du capitalisme de plateforme" (https://www.arretsurimages.net/chroniques/clic-gauche/aux-apatrides-du-web-merdique).

ou "dégradation délibérée du service".

dégradation, délabrement, dévastation, endommagement (+- endommagé), dégât, destruction (de certaines parties) ; si intentionnel : saccage, ravage, vandalisme. Ensuite, on peut préciser, d'un adjectif ou complément, l'ampleur, l'origine, la cause…

The more formal "platform decay" is mentionned as an english equivalent.
Starting from the multiple meaning of decay, we can translate it :

pourrissement inévitable (des plateformes) [insist on it coming from the inside]
dégradation/déclin naturel du service rendu par les plateformes. [more descriptive]

One could imagine also in reference to the famous urbérisation, the term pourrisation, describing a platform offering a service more and more pourri to its customers.

« Pourrissement », du point de vue figuré n'est rien d'autre que « dégradation » (TLFi), et donc , d'un terme qu'on voudrait croire assez spécifique (« merdification ») on passe à un terme qui fait abstraction de cela, c'est à dire un terme plus général ; je ne pense pas que l'on ait un véritable synonyme puisque « merdification », si ce n'est pas un mot bien défini, dans les définitions variées qu'on lui trouve, implique les termes « plateforme », « capitalisme », « service », « clientèle ».

@LPH Effectivement, le terme anglais est tellement spécifique au concept énoncé, on peut difficilement le remplacer par un terme français sans préciser dans la phrase de quoi il s'agit.

Also {pourrissement | moisissure | rancissement | blettissement} des plateformes: platform {rotting | molding | rancidity | decay}.

…  corruption ; décadence ; décomposition ; dégénérescence ; dénaturation ; détérioration ; perversion.

ou encore érosion, désagrégation

I'd simply go with "détérioration (progressive)", which seems to me closer than 'dégradation' for some reason.
Or, maybe slightly more casually: "empirement" (worsening) from "empirer" (to worsen).
I'd also suggest "détérioration systémique" if the point of the sentence is to highlight the systemic aspects of enshitiffication as opposed to specific events, depending on the text I might even go for the full "détérioration progressive et systémiques (des plateformes digitales)" to convey the full picture.
I do believe most translations with a change of register would tend towards being more convoluted to get more specific so as to satisfy the need of capturing the narrow semantic support of the term stemming from its relatively recent inception (2022-2023) and cultural lack of a generalizable conceptual understanding of the process. That is to say, similarly specific and concise formal words have yet to have taken hold, and may come from an interaction with the socio-political causes of enshittification, as others have proposed.
